# Version 12.10 wireless not working after upgrade

Tags: wireless, 12.10

I have a Lenovo T 61 unknown wireless adapter and my wireless worked in v 12.04 but no longer connects with v 12.10, what should I do to resolve this problem?

Comment: The T61 was sold with four different wireless cards. Please run lspci -nn and verify yours before you apply any fix. If in doubt, post it here and we'll help.

Answer (score 1):

I found a very similar question, where you have to disable "n":

[How do I get my Lenovo T61 to connect to a wireless network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93447/how-do-i-get-my-lenovo-t61-to-connect-to-a-wireless-network)

check it out, and good luck with your issue!