# Thinkpad X61 (4965agn) wireless not working

Tags: wireless, drivers, thinkpad

So I have had ubuntu for a while now and I have tried literally every solution online, but to no avail, there just seems to be no way to solve this problem: the wifi signal on my x61 is not strong (2 bars out of 3) and the speed is really low, so obviously there is a driver problem, and I know a lot of machines with the intel 4965 wireless card have the same problem. I know x61 is an old machine and ubuntu used to support it, I just don't know if ubuntu stopped including drivers for older machines in the kernel after a certain version, and if this is just the way they do things around here??

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried  [How do I get my Lenovo T61 to connect to a wireless network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93447/how-do-i-get-my-lenovo-t61-to-connect-to-a-wireless-network/118968#118968)    ?
After I did this, my connection is stable and 54Mb/s

EPA