# I have partially uninstalled wireless driver iwl4965, wireless never worked, no option to install proprietary drivers

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers, proprietary

Still need some help or ideas even.  After trying all suggestions from @Chil and @Dav see comments below (the @ sign signals them I've responded in some way to the question right? I still have the same problem.

I can "see" wireless networks but I can't connect.  I have fresh results to the all in one wireless script at >http://paste.ubuntu.com/13206822>, perhaps someone can make sense of this for me and free me from the tripping hazard clinging to my laptop and dragging across the living room floor, down the hall and into the common room.  Thanks, Desi

**Thank you David Foerster for your review of my post and recommendation to review, "How do I get my Lenovo T61 to connect to a wireless network?" The solution for that issue is possibly restricted to Ubuntu 11.04 & 11.10 depending, I suppose, on the accuracy of the wording in that post, please correct me if otherwise. I did, in any event, try the recommendation but it did solve my problem.**

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, I installed with the Internal Network Adapter Boot disabled in the BIOS.  USB's didn't work until I enabled the Internal Network Adapter.  Wireless has never worked but did identify available wireless networks.  Wired Connection works just fine.

I have tried for several hours over several days to load the drivers for the "Intel Pro/Wireless 4965 AG or AGN Kedron" wireless controller.  (I'm new) Additionally when I installed Ubuntu I accidentally didn't select "allowing for proprietary drivers"

The additional drivers tab,(System Settings/Software & Updates/) is empty, the search comes up negative.  I have since installed Ubuntu-extras thinking that would help.  I discovered the iwlagn Driver on the Intel site and thought that my solution.  I tried to remove the existing iwl4965 Driver and was only partially successful.

I was not confident I found the correct info on how to install the Driver recommended by Intel-they suggested adding the drivers directly to (libraries?)  I need help cleaning up the mess I've made and installing the proper driver so I can finally have freedom from my Ethernet tether.

I would also like to undo the installation "error/choice" when I selected "no proprietary" drivers - if necessary. Here is some info based on what others have been advised to provide.

Scratch that I followed the recommendation the popped up as I tried to submit my question to run the Wired/Wireless all in One script.  I'll will remove most of what I had intended as it is all replaced and more at:http://paste.ubuntu.com/13141481/

I hope you can help.

```
desi@desi-HP-Compaq-8510p:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release; uname -a
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"
Linux desi-HP-Compaq-8510p 3.19.0-32-generic #37~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 22 09:41:40 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

desi@desi-HP-Compaq-8510p:~$ lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82566MM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1049] (rev 03)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:30c5]
Kernel driver in use: e1000e

10:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 4965 AG or AGN [Kedron] Network Connection [8086:4229] (rev 61)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1000]
```

The following is why I believe I only partially uninstalled the wireless driver....

```
desi@desi-HP-Compaq-8510p:~$ cat /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
```

I'm sure the all in one script will contain a more accurate assessment of my troubles than I was able to cobble together....so I removed several pages of additional info the recommended substitute All in One Script can be found at old link - paste_ubuntu_com/13141481/.

Thanks again for your consideration.

Desi
ps.  while going through the recommended wireless "solutions" I did the following....`sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer` ....now I realize that's for a broadcom chip set right?  Can it be undone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get my Lenovo T61 to connect to a wireless network?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/93447/how-do-i-get-my-lenovo-t61-to-connect-to-a-wireless-network)

Comment: channel 1 is the most crowded channel in your very congested area. You seriously need to set your router to broadcast over a different channel, preferably one that is not in use or won't interfere as much with your neighboring networks.

Comment: there is nobody on channel 9, channel 9 is a good channel and make sure your router is not broadcasting "n only" and that it is broadcasting bg or you may need to enable wireless n on ubuntu.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your connection issues? What **exactly** happens when you try to connect to your network? On the face of it, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with your drivers or iwlwifi.conf file - and the device seems to be enabled and scanning plenty of access points.

Comment: 1.  The post suggested by davidfoerster as duplicate is relevant to  <= 12.04 versions of Ubuntu, I'm running 14.04.  please refrain from the easy "click to help" by up-voting that suggestion.    2.  mchid thanks but I change channels regularly how should I enable "n" on Ubuntu?    3.  @steeldriver  I click on the "updown" connectivity arrows in the upper right hand corner of the desktop screen.  + I can see available routers including mine, + I select my router, the wifi icon "pulses" for a bit. + Then nothing, no error, no connection just noting. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @kos for the bounty, at least one knight, mercenary?  has taken up the call specifically motivated by your generosity, others have commented too.  Thank you.

Comment: Can you add the output of terminal command `nmcli con list` as well please?

Comment: No problem, really, +50 is difficult for a new user to earn (and hence to set on their own question), and the question is useful, well written and detailed, so it deserved it. Just let me know at any point if any of the answer you receive works, so that I can award the bounty to the working answer.

Comment: @steeldriver  nmcli con list
NAME                      UUID                                   TYPE              TIMESTAMP-REAL                    
Wired connection 1        958cff2c-4a4d-4b14-af5f-33e3ac65ec32   802-3-ethernet    Fri 20 Nov 2015 10:29:28 PM PST   
2WIRE260                  957086b3-b19f-4384-809c-387a1c5a4372   802-11-wireless   never          **what do you think?**

Answer (score 12):

First of all, the installation of `firmware-b43-installer` is inconsequential. It will do no harm and needn't be undone.

Second, the correct driver, iwl4965 is blacklisted, preventing it from loading on boot. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Use nano, kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Remove the very last line which now reads: `blacklist iwl4965`. Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, the contents of the file you quoted, `/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf`, appear correct and are, in any case, not relevant to your troubles.

We see several attempts and failures to connect to your access point. Please carefully check the password. For example, ChiliPepper is not the same as chilipepper. Second,  check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.  Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

If these changes do not help, please try:

```
sudo -i
echo "options iwl4965 11n_disable=1"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/iwl4965.conf
exit
```

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement.

EDIT: Network Manager will default to the usually faster and more secure ethernet if it is available. I notice that, when you ran the wireless_script, ethernet was connected. As we attempt to troubleshoot wireless, please be certain that the ethernet is detached.

We don't know much about why the wireless will not connect. Please look for clues here:

```
cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i network | tail -n25
```

Post the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Let's try to compile the very latest driver. Download this package to your desktop: https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2015/11/15/backports-20151115.tar.gz Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now, back to the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
cd ~/Desktop/backports-20151115
make defconfig-wifi
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot and tell us if there is any improvement.

Comment: Thanks chili555 for your help, thanks too to KGIII for reformating my question ( I was unable to find a way to thank KGIII directly and would still like to).  Chili I tried all of your suggestions, following your directions very carefully.  I noticed after saving the changes using the gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda command, sudo iw reg get came back 00 - I rebooted and regdomain=US. Please help some more, I'd love to get this problem corrected and the journey is exposing me to more and more of what I seem to thoroughly enjoy.  Desi  ps.  I can't find the command for the all in one script.

Comment: **replacement comment for recent deletion** @chili555 I figured out how to re-run the all-in-one script. I got clever and took a chance walking through posting a duplicate wireless question, I found the script language via the links as I did with my original question.  Results of all in one can be found at (http://paste.ubuntu.com/13206822/)   Hopefully I understood the mini-Markdown formatting standards and all appropriate parties are notified. I'm back where I started from, I can see wireless networks, I just can't connect. desi

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: Step One:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/13376938/, installing newest drivers etc. in several hours.

Comment: I should have asked this hours ago.  I'm stuck at:

Comment: desi@desi-HP-Compaq-8510p:~/Desktop$ make defconfig-wifi
make: *** No rule to make target `defconfig-wifi'.  Stop.  I'll keep working at it.

Comment: @Chilli I stuck with it, realized my error referenced directly above, went though the process and no luck.  I still see the available networks and cannot join.  I've uploaded the last few lines of the sudo make install command at (http://paste.ubuntu.com/13389084/)

Comment: @Chilli Last comment for the night.  Just for kicks I tried to login to another password protected network, <-> immediately a dialog box popped up asking for password, <-> I entered a bogus string, within a second the dialog box popped back up asking to confirm password.  <-> I entered a bogus string.  <-> The wifi icon pulsed 5 seconds <->  then nothing but the small note in the upper right hand corner that I was disconnected.  <-> I tried the whole process again, and have never been asked for a password, I choose a network, the icon pulses, I get a message I am disconnected.

Comment: Your paste shows a perfect connection to ethernet. We are interested in wireless. Next, your attempt to connect to a random encrypted network with a "bogus string" produces the correct expected behavior; that is, Network Manager asks again, implying that the password you provided is incorrect. What happens when you attempt to connect to your own network where the password is known? `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i network | tail -n25` Again, with the ethernet disconnected.

Comment: @chilli I greatly appreciate your perseverance.  I'm am lucky enough to be vacationing this week past the high desert and up into the tall mountains.  Alas I may have undone the value of the reward as I no longer have access to my router, however, I have new information to relay which may yet lead to an answer in short order thus ensuring you collect kos's offer.  As you have risen to the call, if we can't clear this up before it expires I will provide you half the bounty (I'm already up to 41 reps) , unless I can encourage kos to extend his offer ;).

Comment: @chilli and others?  Quite by accident, I found I was able, to access the mobile hotspot I enabled, for this very trip.   Now that I am high in the mountains I am able, without any effort or issue, to connect to the wireless router of my hosts A1 ski chalet.  Now before any fiery comments fly, which I hope I have not neglectfully earned, I set up 2 laptops with Ubuntu 14.04 following identical procedures.  The second laptop running Ubuntu has never had any problem connecting to my ATT router, neither the desktop machine running windows 10 in my home office.  Still hoping for a solution.

Comment: @chilli and others? Last comment for the night.  I verified the wireless network settings are identical for the wifi network I am connected to now, in the mountains, and my home wifi network back at sea level, with the exception of: the IPv6 settings, home network set to ignore, and in the general settings tab, the mountain network has Auto connect....and All users may connect.......selected.  Thanks to all.  P.s to answer chilli's recent question.  When I chose the home network, yesterday, the wifi icon pulses for a long while, 6-10 seconds, then a text box pops up, "you are now disconnected"

Comment: May we see another wireless_script run near your home network and with the ethernet detached? I am glad we're making progress!

Comment: @Chilli I Can't provide wireless_script until I return home Sunday 11/29/15.  Thanks for sticking with this.

Comment: @dharamija I awarded the bounty to this answer since beside having fixed your issue, which is something still unknown, for sure it provided lots of informations and debugging resources also for future readers. Let me know if this actually fixed your specific issue as well when you have the chance to test.

Comment: @chilli I've uploaded the results of 'cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i network | tail -n25the' at (http://paste.ubuntu.com/13589703/).  I pasted 2 results.  1st.  failure to access my home network, ether net cable disconnected, 2nd. after successfully accessing my mobile hotspot, ether net cable disconnected. Result of both look identical, excepting the Ipv6 bit.  I have since changed the mobile hot-spot Network settings to "ignore" in Ipv6.  I'm glad kos awarded you the bounty, you have put a lot of effort into this problem.  Hope you can yet solve it.  Thanks, desi.

Comment: In both, you are well and truly connected! Please see: "NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL". What are you unable to do? Surf the web from Firefox? Get updates? Or what??

Comment: @dharamija It's not clear whether you solved your problem or not, can you point that out explicitly? If there's a problem, which is the problem^

Comment: @chilli unfortunately I cannot  connect to my home network, and have never connected.   When I select my home network, the wireless icon pulses for a significant length of time and I get a window in the upper right hand corner of the screen that says, you are now disconnected.  The wireless icon indicates "non connection".  I have successfully connected via a mobile hotspot - the second result pasted at paste.ubuntu.com from the cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i network | tail -n25 code and at a friends network while I was out of town last week.  But never on my home network.

Comment: Your comment above says: "1st. failure to access my home network, ether net cable disconnected, " and the referenced paste says: "after unsuccessful connection to home wireless network, no ethernet connected." However, the paste shows a perfect connection and, as I said, "NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL". I see no failure to connect.  Where is the log showing it so we may troubleshoot?

Comment: In the meantime I'll set another bounty. I don't like half-things!

Comment: @chilli perhaps I fumbled the previous post to paste.ubuntu.  Here is the results of 'cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i network | tail -n25' after failure to connect to my home network. [http://paste.ubuntu.com/13695521/]

Comment: @chilli I apologize another fumble, the previous paste bin upload "no longer exists" as of this evening and I can't seem to edit it.  Please find the the results of 'cat /var/log/syslog | grep -i network | tail -n25' at http://paste.ubuntu.com/13737921/.  It reveals the process of scanning, authenticating and disconnection (about 15-20 seconds) that ultimately leads to  "Activation (wlan0/wireless): association took too long, failing activation."